# Instantiate new ViewController Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

I want to instantiate a new ViewController to use with PushViewController and subscribe to events. However, when I do this I get an error saying that I need to pass an "IntPtr" parameter. What is this, how should I go about it?

[image]

Update: Read "mystoryPage" instead of "storyController".

Answer (score 0):

If your UIViewController is coming from a storyboard/xib, add a default constructor to your `storyPageScroll` class that calls the base `initWithNibName:bundle:` constructor:

```
public storyPageScroll() : base("storyPageController", null)
{
}
```

Usage:

```
var storyController = new storyPageScroll();
```

Otherwise add a base constructor that calls the `init` constructor:

```
public storyPageScroll() : base (NSObjectFlag.Empty)
{
}
```

Comment: Your first solution gives me two errors, 1. the method doesn't have a return type, and 2. Unexpected character ':'.

Comment: I updated it to match your `storyPageScroll` class name

Comment: Your `storyPageScroll` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`??? If so why are you trying to cast it to a UIViewController? They are not the same base classes....

Comment: Here's the deal, this is my design: mystoryPage (UIViewController) > storyPageScroll (Scroll View). I changed the names in my original post by mistake. I need to subscribe to an event by the Scroll View from my root view controller, which is not the "mystoryPage".